# FutureWarning: The alias _() will be deprecated. Use _i18n() instead

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook, package

c:\users\saiyan goku\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\transutils.py:13: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.

How to get rid of this Future warning error which is shown in command line of python?

Comment: Same, get this message when running some jupyter lab commands. Basically, all jupyter* packages are the latest, no need to upgrade. I think it's just a warning, no error met so far.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same question and I solved it by
`conda install nbclassic==0.3.2`

Comment: Does anyone know why this occurs? The solution is indeed proposed at other locations as well, however, it does not seem future proof since version 0.3.5 of nbclassic is noted to cause this issue. 

https://pythonshowcase.com/question/error-launching-jupyter-lab-in-new-environment